# Which is better and faster "INNER JOIN" or "WHERE".. while updating a table records?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sql-update, where-clause

I have to tables "table A" and "table B" and I want to update some records in "table A" matched with "table B" on some conditions. So which is better and faster if I use a "JOIN" or "WHERE" clause to check condition. I have 10 million records in each table. I am using sql server 2008R2.

~AvinashK

Comment: Can you show us a sample of each sql?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blogdoezequiel/archive/2012/01/15/t-sql-misconceptions-join-on-vs-where.aspx#.U8YOQXMZ7qA

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you:

```
UPDATE A SET
  A.<field1> = B.<field1>,
  A.<field2> = B.<field2>
FROM A INNER JOIN 
  B ON A.<Field> = B.<field>
WHERE <Conditions>
```